# Retrieve value in order and substract rows using mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am struggling with an issue since two days and I need help.

I would like to make subtraction on consecutive rows in a SQL table but by sorting values before.

For instance I have my table like these :

```
Name       | Activity  |  Day
John | Tennis | Day10
Bob | Swimming | Day9 
Mathilda | Tennis | Day2
John | Swimming | Day2
Bob | Tennis | Day2
John | Computer Science | Day 10
```

In this table, I would like to know for the persons who get more than one activity what is the time between two activities.

So in this example if we can substract days, we see than John and Bob have two activites and the maximum time break for them is reached by John with 8 days.

I have tried to do it like so :

```
SET @previousDay:=0;

SELECT Name, days, @previousDay - day, @previousDay:=day
FROM table
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM table group by Name having count(Name) > 1) 
ORDER BY Name, Day
```

But that is completely false as the ORDER BY is done after the substraction. I do not see the good result because I want to make the substraction with consecutive values for days sorted.

It seems that I can't sort the IN result so do you know if there is a way to solve my issue ?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

BTW : I do not know how to format correctly the table so any help would be appreciated thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select t.*, (previousDay - day) as diff
from (select t.*,
             (@pd := (case when @n <> name
                           then if(@n := name, NULL, NULL) -- does happen
                           when (@tmp_pd := @pd) = null then null       -- never happens
                           when (@pd := day) = null then null   -- never happens
                           else @tmp_pd
                      end)
             ) as previousDay
      from t cross join
           (select @n := '', @pd = -1) params
      order by name, day
     ) t
where previousDay is not null;
```

Note that this goes through a great effort to put all the operations on variables in a single expression (hence the weird `= NULL` in the `case` conditions).  The reason is that MysQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` clause, so multiple assignments might be evaluated in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your comment, that is really helpful.
Unfornately I get only null values because of the @n<> name condition on my table i don't know why.

I have tried to assign the value name to @n in the select query but it does not change anything.

I am going to try to solve this.

Thanks a lot for your answer I have learnt a lot by seeing your code.

Comment: @Mike . . . I left something out.